# Do we have a website to search packages and get conda commands to install python packages like we have for Javascript?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda

I am using conda to create environment and install packages to my python app. I am looking for a website where I can find the command to run by searching the package name. Is there a website like that? For example we have for javascript https://www.npmjs.com/. I find one for python https://libraries.io/ but it does not mention conda command. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, depending on your package manager:

- PyPI (`pip install`):  https://pypi.org/
- Anaconda Cloud (`conda install`): https://anaconda.org

Comment: Thanks! I wanted https://anaconda.org this website. However I am having trouble choosing one from the search results when I search a package by name. For example if I search "pyqt", I get all results with owners. And each result says to install using 'c' option with the name of owner. Which one should I choose? Is it mandatory to give this 'c' option while installing package? for example, I see "conda install -c conda-forge pyqt" So can I just run command "conda install pyqt" And does this work for all packages?

Comment: As its written here: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html, the -c is "Additional channel to search for packages. These are URLs searched in the order" 
so it doesn't matter if you don't specified it (for your use case)